Solving the unsolvable 15 puzzle
I got this new sliding-block puzzle. There is a 4x4 square wooden tray with fifteen 1x1 square tiles. The tiles can slide around inside the tray without overlapping by using the one empty space.
This particular puzzle has solid-colored tiles that form a red-blue gradient -- each tile is a different color. I mixed up the puzzle several times and after a little practice I got pretty good at solving it back to the original gradient configuration.
Then, I showed the puzzle to my friend. She said she wanted to mix it up for me, so I handed it to her and watched her slide the tiles around to mix them up, although I lost track of the exact moves she made. When she handed the puzzle back to me, I couldn't solve it. I got close -- I got to the point where only the last two tiles on the bottom row were swapped with each other.
Eventually, I came up with a mathematical proof that the puzzle was impossible -- which made no sense, because I watched the puzzle get into its current configuration, and reversing those steps, if I could remember them, would surely solve it!
When I showed my friend the proof, she laughed and told me I would figure it out eventually. What am I missing?

(This is an original puzzle. The story is fictional. There is a specific intended solution.)

One way to solve this would be

 to turn the puzzle 90° and start over from there.

This will work since

 any starting configuration (with the hole in the correct spot) is solvable if and only if the tiles are an even permutation away from the solved state. Now, suppose we rotate the puzzle sideways and slide the hole to its now correct spot. As a permutation of the tiles, this is acting on the central $2\times 2$ by a 4-cycle and on the outer ring by the third power of an 11-cycle. Hence, an odd permutation overall. As such, changing your perspective this way will exactly exchange the solvable and unsovable states.


Curiously enough, this solution will not work for all larger grids but only if the sidelength is

 divisible by four.

This is because

 we can easily determine the cycle decomposition of the effect of the 90° rotation in general: The outer broken ring will be affected by some power of an odd cycle and therefore contribute an even part to the whole permutation. As such, the parity only depends on the inner tiles, which are split into a collection of 4-cycles (except the center, for an odd sidelength). Therefore, the parity of the rotation coincides with the parity of the number of 4-cycles in the center. Now, if the sidelength of the inner square, call it $n$ is odd, there will be exactly $n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$ tiles on 4-cycles. This number is divisible by 8 (since both factors are even and one must be divisible by 4). Hence, the number of 4-cycles is even, so that the rotation will not change the parity. On the other hand, if $n$ is even, there will be $n^2$ tiles on 4-cycles. Hence, there will be an even number of these if and only if $n$ is also divisible by 4. In total, the rotation will change the parity if and only if the sidelength of the inner square is even but not divisible by 4, i.e. exactly when the sidelength of the whole grid is divisible by 4.


I was wondering why the puzzle used the odd and somewhat harder to read color gradient, instead of the usual numbers!

Instead of colors, the tiles could show different numbers of concentric circles.

@NuclearHoagie should have gone for 15 shades of grey.

@infinitezero: My thought was that there was an optical illusion where two of the squares were secretly the same color; using 15 shades of gray would raise similar issues.  I think a combination of an overlaid circle, plus, square, and X having place values of 1, 2, 4, and 8 might be cleanest and most unambiguous.

@supercat it was a joke. There's a popular bdsm novel(?) called 50 shades of gray.

@infinitezero: Ah.  I had been pondering whether the puzzle might be made more subtle by having one or maybe two groups of four tiles which were rotated versions of each other.  I think trying to have three such groups would break the puzzle, though.
